# Setting up a comments section in expression engine

Tags: ee2, forms, module, comment-form, comments

I am working on my blog/tutorial site and I have it set up so the main page displays my content and the user can click on an individual entry and go to a page that displays just that entry through my "video_tutorial" template. I have the comment module installed and have been adding in some comment tags and such, however nothing is showing up. So I am not sure if I am using the wrong tags or what, so I thought I would start over and get some feedback first.

I am not sure if this is something I just need to enable somewhere in expression engine or if I need to use another language. I just need the user to be able to enter a name and a comment. I have seen some examples of adding facebook logins, I don't need to go that direction, if Expression Engine has a commenting system built in that would work for me assuming I can still style it.

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/comment/index.html#id11 
I have used this as a basis and I used the code it has in the "comment submission form" area thinking that would assist me but to no success. I swapped out the channel with what I needed too. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is my code for my "video_tutorial" template which is set up to show a single entry and I want the comment section to go underneath there for users to discuss the content of the video or learn among themselves as well.

Revised Code in my video_tutorial/comment template group/template

```
{exp:comment:form channel="video_tutorial" url_title="video_tutorial/comment" preview="channel/preview"}

    {if logged_out}
            <label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" value="{name}" size="50" /><br />
            <label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" value="{email}" size="50" /><br />
            <label for="location">Location:</label> <input type="text" name="location" value="{location}" size="50" /><br />
            <label for="url">URL:</label> <input type="text" name="url" value="{url}" size="50" /><br />
    {/if}

    <label for="comment">Comment:</label><br />
    <textarea name="comment" cols="70" rows="10">{comment}</textarea>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="save_info" value="yes" {save_info} /> Remember my personal information</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="notify_me" value="yes" {notify_me} /> Notify me of follow-up comments?</label><br />

    {if captcha}
            <label for="captcha">Please enter the word you see in the image below:</label><br />
            <p>{captcha}<br />
            <input type="text" name="captcha" value="{captcha_word}" maxlength="20" /></p>
    {/if}

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview" />

{/exp:comment:form}
```

Here is my code for my video_tutorial template group.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head> 
<title>Reanimated Fallout | Animation & Motion Graphics Tutorials, Training & More</title>

<!-- stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{stylesheet=fallout_stylesheet/fallout_css}" /> 
</head>


<header>
        <div id="buttonbar">
        <div class="wrapper">   
        <div id="navigation">
            <div id="logo">
            <a href= "http://reanimatedfallout.com/index.php?/reanimatedfallout"><img src="images/reanimated_fallout_logo.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<!-- navigation buttons -->

            <div class="wrapper">           
            <ul id="buttons">

                <li>
                <a href= "http://reanimatedfallout.com/index.php?/after_effects"><img src="images/navigation/after_effects_btn.png"></a>
                </li>

                <li> 
                <a href= "http://reanimatedfallout.com/index.php?/cinema_4d"><img src="images/navigation/cinema_4d_btn.png"></a>
                </li>

                <li> 
                <a href= "http://reanimatedfallout.com/index.php?/photoshop"><img src="images/navigation/photoshop_btn.png"></a>
                </li>

                <li> 
                <a href= "http://reanimatedfallout.com/index.php?/premiere"><img src="images/navigation/premiere_btn.png"></a>
                </li>

                <li> 
                <a href= "http://reanimatedfallout.com/index.php?/reviews"><img src="images/navigation/reviews_btn.png"></a>
                </li>

                <li> 
                <a href= "http://reanimatedfallout.com/index.php?/apple"><img src="images/navigation/apple_btn.png"></a>
                </li>

                <li> 
                <a href= "http://reanimatedfallout.com/index.php?/about"><img src="images/navigation/about_btn.png"></a>
                </li>
            </div>
            </ul>


</header>


<body>

{exp:channel:entries channel="video_tutorials" limit="1" sort="entry_date" order="desc"}

{if count==1}
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="video_large">
        <h1><a href="{title_permalink="video_tutorial}">{video_tutorial_title}</a></h1>
        <div class="large_reposition">
        <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/{video_tutorial_link}?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="900" height="506" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> 
        <h3>{video_tutorial_summary}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
{/if} 
{/exp:channel:entries}


<!-- comments -->

{exp:comment:entries url_title="video_tutorial/comment" sort="asc" limit="100"}
        {comment}
        <p>By {name} on {comment_date format="%Y %m %d"}</p>
{/exp:comment:entries}




<!-- search field -->

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="search">
        {exp:search:simple_form form_class="searchbox" channel="video_tutorials"}
            <p>
                 <input type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="Search" id="keywords" value="" size="24" maxlength="100">
             </p>
        {/exp:search:simple_form}
    </div>

    <div class="contact">
        <p> <label for="keywords">Connect & Contact</label> </p>
        <ul id="contact_btns">

            <li>
            <a href= "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Reanimated-Fallout/242045199141877"><img src="images/social_icons/facebook.png"></a>
            </li>

            <li>
            <a href= "https://twitter.com/chrisreanimated"><img src="images/social_icons/twitter.png"></a>
            </li>

            <li>
            <a href= "https://vimeo.com/user10748580"><img src="images/social_icons/vimeo.png"></a>
            </li>

            <li>
            <a href= "http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=46629295&trk=tab_pro"><img src="images/social_icons/linkedin.png"></a>
            </li>

            <li>
            <a href="mailto:chris@reanimatedfallout.com""><img src="images/social_icons/email.png"></a>
            </li>
    </div>

    <div class="donate">
        <p> <label for="keywords">Support</label> </p>

            <ul id="donate_btn">
            <li>
            <a href= "https://twitter.com/chrisreanimated"><img src="images/donate_btn.png"></a>
            </li>
    </div>

    <div class="cosmicrage">
            <a href= "http://cosmicragemotioncomic.wordpress.com"><img src="images/cosmic_rage_web_banner_240_2.png"></a>

    </div>

</div>
</div>

</body>

    <footer>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="footer">
                <p class="footerinfo"> &copy; All content designed and developed by Reanimated Fallout.  </p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Chris, can you provide us with the code behind your template?

Comment: thanks. The template that I am working in is designed so there is only one item on it and users will discuss that item.

Answer (score 4):

Your example code shows you doing two things:

1. Listing any existing comments on the entry (`{exp:comment:entries}`)
2. Displaying a list of Channel Entries (`{exp:channel:entries}`)

Nowhere are you displaying the comment form (even though you [linked to the documentation on it](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/comment/index.html#id11)).

However, the comment form is generally meant to be used on a "single entry" template, where the third segment of the URL is an `entry_id` or `url_title` of an entry. This is how the `comment:entries` and `comment:form` tags know which entry they are display from/submitting to. The code you posted indicates to me that you don't fully grasp how EE's URLs and templates work yet ... I'd suggest [reading up on it in the docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/url_structure.html).

If you want to display either of these tags on a page which does *not* contain `entry_id` or `url_title` information in the URL, you'll need to provide an `entry_id` to each tag via their `entry_id` tag parameter - generally by [embedding those chunks of code](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/embedding.html) and passing it via an embed variable.

**UPDATE:**

These two (simplified - no header or footer HTML) templates should get you started in understanding how it works.

First is your **video_tutorial/index** template. This provides a listing of your tutorials, each with a link to its "permalink".

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="video_tutorials" limit="5" paginate="bottom"}
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="video_large">
        <h1><a href="{title_permalink="video_tutorial/entry"}">{video_tutorial_title}</a></h1>
        <div class="large_reposition">
        <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/{video_tutorial_link}?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="900" height="506" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> 
        <h3>{video_tutorial_summary}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{paginate}
    <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
{/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The next is your **video_tutorial/entry** template. This is where you'll display all of your entry's data, plus any comments on the entry, and the comment form. Note that the fact that this template is called **entry** is irrelevant - you can call it anything you want, so long as you change that value in the `{title_permalink}` path in your **index** template.

```
{!-- Display your entry, as this is the "permalink" page for this entry --}

{exp:channel:entries channel="video_tutorials" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}
{if no_results}{redirect="404"}{/if}
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="video_large">
            <h1>{video_tutorial_title}</h1>
            <div class="large_reposition">
            <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/{video_tutorial_link}?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="900" height="506" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> 
            <h3>{video_tutorial_summary}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}

{!-- Display any existing comments. Note that the reason this works here is that the third segment of the URL this template will be displayed at is the `url_title` for this entry, hence the Comment module knows which comments to look for. --}

<h4>Comments</h4>

{exp:comment:entries channel="video_tutorials" sort="asc" limit="100"}
    {comment}
    <p>By {name} on {comment_date format="%Y %m %d"}</p>
{/exp:comment:entries}

{!-- Display the comment form - same story as above with the `url_title` in the URL. Note that for eah of these tags, you *can* pass either a `url_ttle` or `entry_id` as a parameter if you want to display them in a *non* single-entry template. --}

<h4>Add Your Comment</h4>

{exp:comment:form channel="video_tutorials" preview="video_tutorial/preview"}

    {if logged_out}
            <label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" value="{name}" size="50" /><br />
            <label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" value="{email}" size="50" /><br />
            <label for="location">Location:</label> <input type="text" name="location" value="{location}" size="50" /><br />
            <label for="url">URL:</label> <input type="text" name="url" value="{url}" size="50" /><br />
    {/if}
    <label for="comment">Comment:</label><br />
    <textarea name="comment" cols="70" rows="10">{comment}</textarea>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="save_info" value="yes" {save_info} /> Remember my personal information</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="notify_me" value="yes" {notify_me} /> Notify me of follow-up comments?</label><br />
    {if captcha}
            <label for="captcha">Please enter the word you see in the image below:</label><br />
            <p>{captcha}<br />
            <input type="text" name="captcha" value="{captcha_word}" maxlength="20" /></p>
    {/if}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="preview" value="Preview" />

{/exp:comment:form}
```

Comment: I added the form code into the template below the viewing comments code and no form displays. The template that I am working in is designed so there is only one item on it and users will discuss that item.

Comment: What is the URL structure of the page you're viewing?

Comment: http://reanimatedfallout.com/index.php?/video_tutorial

video_tutorial is the template that I have been posting the code for that I would like the comment form and comments in. I have posted up the settings to the comments module as well in a previous post above.

Comment: OK, so as I said above, your URL has no entry info in it. That URL indicates a template where you list several tutorials. Each one should link to a "detail" or "view" template (so, instead of `{title_permalink="video_tutorial"}`, it should be `{'title_permalink="video_tutorial/view"}`. Then your comment tags should live in the `view` template. Again, please read the link I posted above form the EE docs explaining how URLs and templates work in EE.

Comment: Ok, I created a new template within template group video_tutorial. The new template is named "comment" and the only code in that template is the comment form code. I also went back into the main index and converted the {title_permalink="video_tutorial/comment}. Now that I have done I can see the url is creating unique urls for them however there still is no comment form. I have even tried placing the video_tutorial code in the comment template with no success. Right now when you click on a video it just takes you to a white page. This is my first site and I really appreciate the help on this.

Comment: Could you please update your template code snippet to include the bit with the comment form code?  It is hard to figure out where you might be going wrong without seeing what is going on there.  To be specific, right now I am not seeing an `exp:comment:form` anywhere in your template though I do see some form fields.

Comment: I updated the code above with my new template group "video_tutorial" and the template within it called "comments"

Comment: Is it correct to understand that links to this page are taking the form `/video_tutorial/comments/url_title_for_entry` ?

Comment: yes the url appears as:
reanimatedfallout.com/index.php?/video_tutorial/comment/title_of_the_entry

However this page just shows up as blank (white). No imagery or anything.

Comment: Would it help if I posted anything else up?

Comment: Chris - I just added some example template code that should help.

Comment: You can also force-feed the url_title or entry_id to the comments tag, to make sure it looks at the right segment. e.g. `url_title="{segment_3}"`

Comment: @Derek, thanks for the help, it seems to be working. Just working on some styling and such now to get it to match the rest of the site design. I really appreciate your help on my first site. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 2):

In the control panel check out Admin->channel preferences -> channel -> your channel, edit preferences, and them have a look at the "Comment Posting Preferences" section.

You will also want to make sure comments are turned on in the individual entries. The default for new entries is set earlier in the same control panel page.

Comment: In there I have allow comments:on, require membership:no, enable captcha: yes, require email address: no, moderate comments: no, Max character: 5000, comment resubmission interval:3, comment expiration:0, comment text formatting: XHTML, comment HTML formatting: allow only safe html, allow image urls in comments: no, automatically turn urls and email addresses into links: yes.

Comment: Ok and in the individual entries do you have allow comments for this entry turned on in the options tab?

Comment: I have been testing out with 4 sample videos here are the options under all 4...

Channel: video_tutorials
Status: Open
Make entry sticky: no
allow comments: yes